# Proper Use of ORACLE LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join

I have the following query:

```
SELECT eps.PROPOSAL_NUMBER,
       pers.PROP_PERSON_ROLE_ID,
       pers.FULL_NAME,       
       pers.HOME_UNIT
       FROM EPS_PROPOSAL eps
       FULL OUTER JOIN EPS_PROP_PERSON pers USING (PROPOSAL_NUMBER)
       WHERE (pers.PROP_PERSON_ROLE_ID = 'PI' OR 
              pers.PROP_PERSON_ROLE_ID = 'PD' OR 
              pers.PROP_PERSON_ROLE_ID IS NULL); -- 4483
```

However, if I run the following:

```
SELECT COUNT (*) PROPOSAL_NUMBER FROM EPS_PROPOSAL; -- 4504
```

That's a difference of 21.

I went and took a look at the why the difference and sure enough, 21 of the proposals in the `EPS_PROPOSAL` table do not have any people in the `EPS_PROP_PERSON` table with either a `PI` or `PD` role.
It is only possible to have a single person designated as either a `PI` or `PD` per proposal (e.g. there will never be situation where more than one PI/PD would exist per `PROPOSAL_NUMBER`); however, you could have multiple other roles there (I could list them here, but its irrelevant to the question at hand).

How do I modify my query so that it will return the `PROPOSAL_NUMBER` from `EPS_PROPOSAL` and insert `NULL` values for the `pers` columns for those proposals where a proposal does **not** have a `PI` or `PD`?

I thought that this would be related to the `JOIN`, but using `LEFT JOIN` is not helping here.

My `LEFT JOIN` attempt:

```
SELECT eps.PROPOSAL_NUMBER,
       pers.PROP_PERSON_ROLE_ID,
       pers.FULL_NAME,       
       pers.HOME_UNIT
       FROM EPS_PROPOSAL eps
       LEFT JOIN EPS_PROP_PERSON pers USING (PROPOSAL_NUMBER)
       WHERE (pers.PROP_PERSON_ROLE_ID = 'PI' OR 
              pers.PROP_PERSON_ROLE_ID = 'PD' OR 
              pers.PROP_PERSON_ROLE_ID IS NULL); -- 4483
```

Comment: Can you add in your left join attempt? Also, did you make sure your where restrictions are not responsible for the missing rows? Since it is not the same table that the restrictions are being applied from, this could cause the mismatch.

Comment: For your left join, that looks valid. It should return your dataset less ROLE_ID is PI, PD, or NULL, and insert null on any returned records that do not have a `pers` record.

Did you also want to include the entries from `pers` where `PROP_PERSON_ROLE_ID != ANY('PI', 'PD')`?

Comment: One or both of the comments are definitely correct since - rest assured - your join syntax is correct. The question you'll need to answer is what the filtering conditions are doing to your result. Background: oracle 8i and 9i certified dba and anyways 15 years of _oracle_ .

Comment: @Matthew - It is completely omitting those proposals that have other roles except for a PI or PD.  However, you are correct, it is correctly inserting those proposals that have 0 roles for a particular proposal.

Comment: I believe you are correct @Matthew.  I want to include all proposals in my list, but if that proposal doesn't have a PI or PD a want those columns to be NULL.

Comment: If I want to include ALL proposals in my list but make sure that the pers columns are NULL in the case that a proposal doesn't have PI or PD, would that be a LEFT JOIN?

Comment: Yes that's it.  you've understood left joins perfectly

Comment: What is happening though is that the proposal is not being added into my result set at all in that case using the above query.  I want the PROPOSAL_NUMBER to be added there, but keep the pers columns NULL in that case.  The thing that is throwing it off, is in the case that a proposal has other roles (e.g. COI, KP, COD) but no PI or PD.  In that situation that proposal is left off of the list using the above query.

Comment: I see. Yea your last condition should have allowed for that. Then I'm not sure.

Comment: Just move `where` conditions to the `join` conditions: `from eps_proposal eps left join eps_prop_person pers on eps.proposal_number = pers.proposal_number and pers.prop_person_role_id in ('PI', 'PD')`. This will return pers for roles `'PI'` and `'PD'` if any and `null`s for proposals without these roles. And will not reduce `eps_proposal` rows in any way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your explanations in the comments, I believe this is what you are looking for. I am going to use the union operator to combine two like datasets together. One will be your original query for PI and PD and the other I will do an inverse of your predicate. In the bottom query, I am just going to assign NULL as the values from pers, as default.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  PROPOSAL_NUMBER, 
  FIRST_VALUE(PROP_PERSON_ROLE_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY PROPOSAL_NUMBER ORDER BY PROPOSAL_NUMBER), 
  FIRST_VALUE(FULL_NAME) OVER (PARTITION BY PROPOSAL_NUMBER ORDER BY PROPOSAL_NUMBER), 
  FIRST_VALUE(HOME_UNIT) OVER (PARTITION BY PROPOSAL_NUMBER ORDER BY PROPOSAL_NUMBER)
FROM
((
SELECT eps.PROPOSAL_NUMBER,
       pers.PROP_PERSON_ROLE_ID,
       pers.FULL_NAME,       
       pers.HOME_UNIT
       FROM EPS_PROPOSAL eps
       LEFT JOIN EPS_PROP_PERSON pers ON eps.PROPOSAL_NUMBER = pers.PROPOSAL_NUMBER
       WHERE (pers.PROP_PERSON_ROLE_ID = 'PI' OR 
              pers.PROP_PERSON_ROLE_ID = 'PD' OR 
              pers.PROP_PERSON_ROLE_ID IS NULL)
)
UNION
(
SELECT eps.PROPOSAL_NUMBER,
       NULL as PROP_PERSON_ROLE_ID,
       NULL as FULL_NAME,       
       NULL as HOME_UNIT
       FROM EPS_PROPOSAL eps
       LEFT JOIN EPS_PROP_PERSON pers ON eps.PROPOSAL_NUMBER = pers.PROPOSAL_NUMBER
       WHERE (pers.PROP_PERSON_ROLE_ID != 'PI' AND
              pers.PROP_PERSON_ROLE_ID != 'PD' AND
              pers.PROP_PERSON_ROLE_ID IS NOT NULL)
))
```

Comment: ORA-25154: column part of USING clause cannot have qualifier
25154. 00000 -  "column part of USING clause cannot have qualifier"
*Cause:    Columns that are used for a named-join (either a NATURAL join
           or a join with a USING clause) cannot have an explicit qualifier.
*Action:   Remove the qualifier.
Error at Line: 15 Column: 8

Comment: I do not normally use the `USING` clause. From what I can read, use the `ON` clause instead. I will update my answer to include it.

Comment: Thanks @Matthew, but this returned 6748 records.  More records than there are proposals.  Something isn't quite right.

Comment: Hm... Maybe change the bottom query from a LEFT to an INNER join, that way it requires an entry in both tables. The left may be pulling more data than you like in this case. Since I don't have a sandbox I can use, it makes it harder for me to help.

Comment: Still 6748 results returned after making that change.

Comment: From what I can test, this is correct. By doing this query, you MAY be able to get more records back than proposal records. It just depends on how you restrict your records in your person table. If you do not have a unique restriction on EPS_PROP_PERSON.PROPOSAL_NUMBER you can potentially have multiple records for one proposal, which the end result can lead to get a dataset back > than EPS_PROPOSAL count.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250427/discussion-between-matthew-and-ivan-drago).

Answer (score 1):

Move the `WHERE` filters to the `JOIN` condition:

```sql
SELECT eps.PROPOSAL_NUMBER,
       pers.PROP_PERSON_ROLE_ID,
       pers.FULL_NAME,       
       pers.HOME_UNIT
FROM   EPS_PROPOSAL eps
       FULL OUTER JOIN EPS_PROP_PERSON pers
       ON (   eps.PROPOSAL_NUMBER = pers.PROPOSAL_NUMBER
          AND (  pers.PROP_PERSON_ROLE_ID IN ( 'PI', 'PD' )
              OR pers.PROP_PERSON_ROLE_ID IS NULL)
          );
```

or, for a `LEFT JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT eps.PROPOSAL_NUMBER,
       pers.PROP_PERSON_ROLE_ID,
       pers.FULL_NAME,       
       pers.HOME_UNIT
FROM   EPS_PROPOSAL eps
       LEFT JOIN EPS_PROP_PERSON pers
       ON (   eps.PROPOSAL_NUMBER = pers.PROPOSAL_NUMBER
          AND (  pers.PROP_PERSON_ROLE_ID IN ( 'PI', 'PD' )
              OR pers.PROP_PERSON_ROLE_ID IS NULL)
          );
```

If you use a `WHERE` filter then the `JOIN` will be performed and afterwards the rows that do not match will be filtered out which will eliminate rows from both `pers` and `eps` (since you have already joined the tables). If you apply the filters in the join then the `pers` table will be filtered before the join and all the rows from `eps` will be returned.